# Why isn't my image displaying, this is my first time using vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to insert my image using a b-img tag. (I'm using the bootstrap-vue library) When I do so, all I get is the little image icon.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-img src="./img/jawnfinder-logo.png"></b-img>
        <b-nav>
            <b-button variant="primary">Sign-Up</b-button>
            <b-button variant="primary">Login</b-button>
        </b-nav>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the folder that the image is in:

[image]

And here is what my webpage looks like:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Possibly because your `img` directory isn't in `public`...?

Comment: that didn't make a difference

Comment: When you run your app, look into the `src` attribute of the image. Does the file exist in that location?

Comment: I think you want to remove the leading `.`... try doing `src="/img/jawnfinder-logo.png"`

Answer (score 3):

move your image inside `src/assets` then use the image.

```
<img alt="Vue logo" src="@/assets/jawnfinder-logo.png">
```

or

```
<b-img src="@/assets/jawnfinder-logo.png"></b-img>
```

Note: All the files including components,css and image should be inside `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can always import as a module if you don't want to deal with paths.

```
<b-img :src="require('./img/jawnfinder-logo.png')"></b-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue-Loader, it won't know that `src` on `<b-img>` is a project relative URL.  You need to make sure you instruct Vue Loader which props in BootstrapVue are image `src` props:

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/images